# CodePlex TortoiseHG Error while Pushing

Tags: mercurial, push, codeplex

I get this error when i pushed my new source code on codeplex.
Could you please help fast. Thank you.

```
% hg outgoing --template {node}^M https://hg.codeplex.com/mxspli
comparing with https://hg.codeplex.com/mxspli
searching for changes
[command completed successfully Sat Apr 30 15:28:52 2016]
% hg log -T {rev}^M -r 1:2
[command completed successfully Sat Apr 30 15:28:52 2016]
% hg push https://hg.codeplex.com/mxspli
pushing to https://hg.codeplex.com/mxspli
searching for changes
http authorization required for https://hg.codeplex.com/mxspli
realm: CodePlex
 remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: transaction abort!
remote: rollback completed
[command returned code 1 Sat Apr 30 15:29:12 2016]
mxspli%
```

Comment: At least show show **FULL output** of CLI-command `hg push -v  --debug --traceback` - we aren't sensitives here to predict all glitches

Comment: this is the full output

Comment: No... this is output of just `hg push https://hg.codeplex.com/mxspli`, **SEE DIFFERENCE!!!**

Comment: I couldn't do it i get an error but i fixed it. There were corrupted files in .hg folder, so i pulled the source and i copied the new files and i pushed the update and it worked,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i figured it out.

The error was that the files in the `.hg` folder were corrupted, so this is what i did:

- Deleted the .hg folder.
- Pulled the source to a new folder.
- Moved the files from the old folder to the new folder.
- Pushed the files.